# Email "submission" and "relay" event

Tags: smtp

I want to get to the bottom of the term email *"submission"* and *"relay"*. So what does this really mean?

In my  head I have two possible scenarios:

### SCENARIO 1

What the terms mean is:

- *"relaying"* ⟹ *"event of sending email using SMTP protocol"*
- *"submission"* ⟹ *"event of recieving using SMTP protocol"*

In this scenario I have to always tell who in the email chain I am refering to.

### SCENARIO 2:

What the terms mean is:

- *"relaying"* ⟹ *"event of email  passing through any device using SMTP protocol (email is recieved & sent ie. forwarded)"*
- *"submission"* ⟹ *"event of sending using SMTP protocol"*

So which scenario is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scenario 2 is close if "sending" is stated as the initial event, authenticated or authorized, of handing mail to the distribution system of email, handled by mail-transfer-agents. Submission can only happen once during the lifecycle of mail delivery - at the beginning. Any other smtp to smtp transfer between MTAs is named relaying.

The submission split from the ongoings of port 25 is currently defined in [rfc 6409](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6409#section-1). Reading its introduction explains the reason why unrestricted mail relaying needed an additional concept of "authenticated/authorized" sending, thus "submitting" of mail.

So to reiterate a common lifecycle of an email nowadays is

```
client (mail-user-agent) => submission (mail-submission-agent, part of the smtpd) => relay*(n) => delivery
```

If you configure a postfix and even use a traditional mail program as mutt (check their [MailConcept](https://gitlab.com/muttmua/mutt/-/wikis/MailConcept) page), you see how it's very much a lot of small services combined at every step.

Comment: I read also in RFC5321 that when we are talking about "relaying" we should use terms "relay sender" and "relay reciever" or "relay client" and "relay server". Otherwise we can't communicate precisely.